# Get result from activity that opened with intent filter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I have an intent filter like below to open specific activity when custom scheme and host called:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PurchaseActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="payment"
                android:scheme="test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

because I don't open this *PurchaseActivity* via code (it's just an intent-filter that opened automatically when *test://payment* called) I can't call `startActivityForResult`, `registerForActivityResult`, ...

inside *PurchaseActivity* I want to pass data to parent activity before calling `finish()`

Comment: "I want to pass data to parent activity" -- if you did not write the parent activity, then most likely the parent activity is not looking for any data. And, if it is, you will need to talk to the developer of that activity to determine how best to pass data to it.

Comment: Basically you can't do this. There is no way to return data in an `Intent` using scheme-based `Intent`s.